# Debian Jessie removing leafpad

Tags: debian, apt, lxde

I have installed Debian Jessie, in short:

- graphical Installation
- mostly options set to default
- software selected to install:

  - Debian desktop
  - LXDE
  - SSH server
  - standard system utilities

Then execute simply:

```
sudo apt-get remove leafpad
```

This will trigger uninstallation also of lxde and task-lxde-desktop. Then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And this triggers removing of 229 packages, 406MB. boost, python, gnome, xdotool. Name it.

I am assuming that leafpad was last anchor keeping lxde in system, but.. why? Is there a way to mark lxde as "uninstallable"? Also I am using vim as my editor so I really don't need leafpad. How can I uninstall it leaving lxde?

Comment: You can hold a package: `apt-mark hold <package>` Note that this also prevents upgrades of `<package>`.